# Order By in Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I had sql table with two columns  sizename and orderof  . I want to select from that table all the sizenames but in ascending order of the orderof  .Iam using EF6 and Linq to Entities

I had used the Query Like this .But its not working(sorting)

```
   var sizedetails = (from size in enty.StyleSizes
                               where size.OurStyleID == ourstyleid
                               orderby size.Orderof
                               select new
                               {
                                   size.SizeName

                               }).Distinct();


            //var sizedetails = enty .StyleSizes.Where(u => u.OurStyleID == ourstyleid).Select(u => u.SizeName ).Distinct();

            foreach (var sizedet in sizedetails)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(sizedet.SizeName.Trim(), typeof(String));
            }
```

I know this may be already asked. But none of the solution provided in those questions working for me

Comment: have you tried order by after select ???

Comment: hi I tried to answer it in memory class collection please check and let me know if this returns you correct result

Comment: Use `orderby` last. That said, it looks like you're ordering by something (`Orderof`) you're not selecting and then taking the distinct set of that (`SizeName`). Which isn't something that SQL can express easily.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I have to do the Distinct else i may end up in mutliple sizenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since LINQ to Entities translates your query to SQL, ordering before `Distinct` has no effect. And the problem is that after `Distinct` you have no access to the property needed for ordering.

So you need an alternative way, which luckily is the `GroupBy` method - its similar to `Distinct` but allows you to access the properties of the elements sharing the same key. Thus you can order the result based on some aggregates (in your case looks like `Min` is the appropriate):

```
var sizedetails = from size in enty.StyleSizes
                  where size.OurStyleID == ourstyleid
                  group size by size.SizeName into sizeGroup
                  orderby sizeGroup.Min(size => size.Orderof)
                  select new
                  {
                      SizeName = sizeGroup.Key
                  };
```

Comment: @SreenathGanga Thanks, actually I just forgot to remove the `(` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I dint tried with DB but with in memory collection it gives be correct result  .
```

here is my class .

```
class StyleSizes
    {
        public int Orderof { get; set; }
        public string SizeName { get; set; }
         public int OurStyleID { get; set; }
    }
     // logic to ue orderby 
        var list = new List<StyleSizes> {  new StyleSizes { Orderof=2,SizeName="B",OurStyleID=1 },
      new StyleSizes { Orderof=11,SizeName="C" ,OurStyleID=2},
       new StyleSizes { Orderof=9,SizeName="D" ,OurStyleID=1},
       new StyleSizes { Orderof=9,SizeName="D" ,OurStyleID=1},
       new StyleSizes { Orderof=3,SizeName="E" ,OurStyleID=1},
       new StyleSizes { Orderof=4,SizeName="F" ,OurStyleID=1}

    };

    var orderList = list.Where(x=>x.OurStyleID==1).OrderBy(x => x.Orderof).Select(c => new { c.SizeName }).Distinct();
```

Comment: Its working  but when i added the where condition its stops sorting

Comment: Hi @SreenathGanga I checked and if you add where it also worked please see updated answer .